# How to Navigate with using sectionList in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-sectionlist

I create 12 elements section list. This is my code,

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item}) =><Text onPress={() => alert(item)} style={styles.item}>{item}</Text> }
          sections={[
            {title: 'A', data: ['Audi']},
            {title: 'B', data: ['BMW']},
            {title: 'H', data: ['Honda', 'Hyundai']},
            {title: 'J', data: ['Jaguar']},
            {title: 'K', data: ['Kia']},
            {title: 'M', data: ['Mazda','Mercedes-Benz', 'Mitsubishi']},
            {title: 'N', data: ['Nissan']},
            {title: 'T', data: ['Toyota']},
            {title: 'V', data: ['Volkswagen']},
          ]}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Now i need to know if press any item from this list and then navigate to each screens. Which mean if i touch Audi then navigate to Audi page. How to do this? Or any idea how to do this without section-list but looks like it?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to wrap your SectionList screen and the detail screen that you will navigate to,

and in the list screen add an onPress for each  item in the list

```
navigateToDetail = car => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate(DetailScreen, {
     name: car
  }
}

render (){ 
  renderItem={({item}) =><Text onPress={navigateToDetail} style={styles.item}>{item}</Text> }
}
```

and in your details screen you need to do this

```
class DetailScreen extends Component {

 render() {
 const car = this.props.navigation.getParam("name", "novalue)

  return <Text>{car}</Text>
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this detail screen ?  is it new js file ?

Comment: yes according to your question, its a new component , that expects some data to work with

Comment: list screen add an onPress for each item in the list? this is what i asked. How to add onPress in every list item?

Comment: no sorry, i mean to implememt the thing you want , you need 2 screens/components/files to achive that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.Just pass the **section.title or any specific** argument from onPress function. Then implement this code which called in onPress function `this.props.navigation.navigate(parameter)`.In my problem, one of parameter is *Audi* and remember you should create parameter.js(audi.js) file in stacknavigator. This is work for me.